# how to compare a list's elements 3 at a time in prolog

Tags: prolog

Given a list (A) I want to be able to create a new list (B) that contains only the elements of A that are the smallest or the biggest compared to their next and previous element. My problem is that I don't know how to do the comparisons of each element with its previous one. 
(This question may be silly but I'm new to prolog and any help would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with something like that:

```
compareElem([]).
compareElem([H,H1,H2|B]):-compareElem(B), 
                          compare(?Order, H1,H2),
                          compare(?Order, H1, H).
```

where ?Order is the order of comparison (like '<' or '>'). See [compare/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=compare/3).

Some queries:

```
?- compareElem([1,2,3,4,5,6]).
true.

?- compareElem([1,2,3,4,5,3]).
false.
```

of course to apply this example you must ensure that the list has 3n elements, this is just a basic example. Together with this comparison you can generate the other list